# Пунктуация при однородных членах предложения, связанных повторяющимися союзами и/или

Tags: пунктуация

В положении о пищевых добавках есть фраза: "Не допускается применение пищевых добавок и ароматизаторов для сокрытия порчи и недоброкачественности сырья или готовой пищевой продукции и/или их фальсификации, и/или с целью введения в заблуждение приобретателей (потребителей)". Не должно ли быть запятой перед первым союзом и/или?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, запятая нужна и перед первым "и/или", и перед вторым.

"Или" (стоящее отдельно, без "и") связывает между собой однородные члены "сырья" и "готовой пищевой продукции", которые относятся к "недоброкачественности". А "их фальсификации" связывается как однородный член с "для сокрытия порчи и недоброкачественности", а дальше по тексту и со "с целью введения в заблуждение потребителей".

Согласно [Розенталю](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=73) при отсутствии "и" перед первым членом и повторении союза хотя бы дважды запятая ставится и перед первым "и". Рискну предположить, что и в случае с "и/или" это правило действует, то есть запятая нужна перед обоими "и/или".

Comment: Тогда и перед вторым и/или не нужна?

Comment: Поскольку это однородные члены, нужна. Я сам поначалу подумал, что она не нужна, а потом, вдумавшись в смысл, понял, что всё-таки нет — нужна.

Comment: Тогда тут получается три однородных, связанных повторяющимся союзом и/или:  "для сокрытия порчи и недоброкачественности", и /или  их фальсификации", и/или "с целью введения в заблуждение". Согласно Розенталю нужно ставить перед каждым союзом и запятую. Схема О, и/или О, и/или О. Как Вы думаете?

Comment: Я думала, что "для сокрытия порчи и недоброкачественности сырья или готовой пищевой продукции и/или их фальсификации" можно рассматривать как однородные, образующие в данном контексте смысловое единство, но тогда перед второй и/или запятая не ставится (согласно Розенталю).

Comment: Мне кажется, что это не тот случай, где смысловое единство. Точно, по Розенталю запятая ставится ***и перед первым*** союзом. Я был неправ! Значит, видимо, нужны обе запятые.

Comment: Насчёт тесного смыслового единства я не уверен, что вообще правильно понимаю его. Я думал, что это что-то, образующее фразеологизмы. Надеюсь, кто-то прокомментирует, кто это понимает. Или, может, Вы, Стася, правильнее меня понимаете и тоже скажете хотя бы предположительно, что это, если я неправ.

Comment: Артём, могу сослаться на Розенталя: "При двух однородных членах с повторяющимся союзом и запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов), например: Были и лето и осень дождливы... (Жуковский); Кругом было и светло и зелено (Тургенев); Ой, полна, полна коробушка, есть и ситец и парча (Некрасов); Он ею и жил и дышал (А.К. Толстой); Прибрежная полоса, пересеченная мысами, уходила и в ту и в другую сторону (Семушкин)".

Answer (score 0):

Фраза перегружена союзами и/или, которые трудно отнести к чему-либо однозначно; восприятие затруднено и сочетанием "ароматизаторов для сокрытия порчи". При этом "введение в заблуждение" по смыслу относится ко всему вместе (не подходит и/или). Я бы изменил так:

> ...в целях сокрытия порчи и недоброкачественности, либо фальсификации
>   сырья или готовой пищевой продукции - с намерением введения в
>   заблуждение приобретателей (потребителей).

Comment: Смысл в том, что нельзя поменять, нужна как цитата.

Comment: _Стася: Смысл в том, что нельзя поменять, нужна как цитата_. === Если это цитата, то берите её полностью вместе со всеми имеющимися в первоисточнике знаками препинания.

Comment: Дело в том, что очень часто в ГОСТах и официальных документах допущены пунктуационные ошибки. Не хочется цитировать выдержки, в которых присутствуют ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

В примере, который вы приводите, союзы следует считать не повторяющимися, а одиночными, соединяющими пары однородных членов предложения (пищевых добавок и ароматизаторов; порчи и недоброкачественности сырья; готовой пищевой продукции и/или их фальсификации). Последнее же предложение с союзом **или/и** не входит в однородный ряд, т.к. здесь предложение с союзом **или/и** выполняет относительно однородного ряда  функцию обстоятельства цели (с какой целью?).

Поэтому запятая перед последним союзом нужна.

См.: [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина, примечание к § 28.](http://%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)